# Disabling HTML entities expanding in HTML::TreeBuilder Perl module

Tags: html, perl, parsing

Consider the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

sub test
{
  my ($content) = @_;

  my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
  $tree->implicit_tags(0);
  $tree->no_expand_entities(1);
  $tree->parse_content($content);

  return $tree->as_HTML(q{<>&});
}

print test('test&laquo;');
print "\n";
print test('<a href="#" title="&laquo;"></a>')
```

It'll print:

```
<html>test&laquo;</html>
<html><a href="#" title="?"></a></html>
```

Due to calling `no_expand_entities(1)` HTML entity `&laquo;` is not expanded within HTML element. However for some reason this mode does not change default behavior for attributes - the same entity is expanded and displayed as garbage.

Could you please advise how to force disabling entities expansion within HTML attributes?

Comment: Why do you think it's "garbage"? Note that you have to set stdout encoding to utf8 if you have a utf8 terminal: `binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';`.

Comment: Well, of course it's not garbage. It's a character corresponding to `&lquot;`. The problem is that I do not want this entity to be expanded at all.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can call

```
$tree->attr_encoded(1);
```

before calling the parser. This would disable `HTML::Parser`'s automatic decoding of attributes.

But best is to ask the author of `HTML::TreeBuilder` (e.g. via rt.cpan.org) to do this automatically if `no_expand_entities` is set.